# Python: pytype-compatible type() command?

Tags: python, types, pytype

Is there any `type`-like command that will recurse through collections to return a pytype-style declaration if such a thing exists?  I realize that collections with heterogeneous elements may be problematic.

For example, I would like to see output similar to this:

```
>>> fancy_type({1: {"a": 2.2}})
dict[int, dict[str, float]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no such function exist. However, it seems fairly simple to write a function as you described in your question:

```
from typing import Iterable, Mapping


def pretty_type(obj):
    obj_type = type(obj).__name__
    if isinstance(obj, Mapping):
        k, v = next(iter(obj.items()))
        return '{}[{}, {}]'.format(obj_type, pretty_type(k), pretty_type(v))
    elif isinstance(obj, Iterable) and not isinstance(obj, str):
        return '{}[{}]'.format(obj_type, pretty_type(obj[0]))
    else:
        return obj_type
```

**Testing**

```
>>> print(pretty_type(0))
int
>>> print(pretty_type({1:{"a":2.2}}))
dict[int, dict[str, float]]
>>> print(pretty_type([1, 2, 3]))
list[int]
>>> print(pretty_type([{1:'a'}, {2:'b'}]))
list[dict[int, str]]
>>>
```

The above code could be extend pretty easily to suit any custom input/ouput. Of course, the code obviously assumes homogeneity between elements. As you noted in your question, heterogeneous elements would be problematic, and in my opinion it really would depend on one's tastes for how they would want to deal with such cases.